# Beautiful Soup not returning anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Hi Im trying to use Beautiful Soup to webscrape off of a website and print facts. This is the website https://fungenerators.com/random/facts/animal/weasel. Im trying to webscrape the fact, although it always ends up printing [] Any idea whats wrong with my code??

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scrape = "https://fungenerators.com/random/facts/animal/weasel"

request_page = urlopen(scrape)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

fact = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="wow fadeInUp animated animated")

print(fact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The element you want is under an `h2` tag, not a `div`.
2. Since some of the data is loaded dynamically, the class-name changes, and removes the second appearance of the word "animated". Instead of the class-name being `wow fadeInUp animated animated` it is `wow fadeInUp animated`.

See the following example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scrape = "https://fungenerators.com/random/facts/animal/weasel"

request_page = urlopen(scrape)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

fact = html_soup.find_all('h2', class_="wow fadeInUp animated")

print(fact)
```

---

(Since there's only one tag, you might want to consider using [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) instead of `find_all()`, in order to get the text using the `.text` method):

```
...
fact = html_soup.find('h2', class_="wow fadeInUp animated").text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my code instead!!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://fungenerators.com/random/facts/animal/weasel')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

result = soup.select('div.wow.fadeInUp.animated.animated')

print(result[0].text)
```

And result would be:

```
Random Weasel  Fact
```

Or if you don't want to use css selectors then you could do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://fungenerators.com/random/facts/animal/weasel')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find_all('h2', class_="wow fadeInUp animated")

print(result[0].text)
```